# SQL Server: how to select values NOT IN the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table look like this :

```
ID    |  NAME
1     | name1
2     | name2
NULL  | name3
3     | name4
```

For a list of customers I want those who are not in the list, something like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM CUSTOMERS c 
WHERE c.ID NOT IN (1,3)
```

But this query does not gives all the wanted lines, as i want to see the null values.

Thanks guys

Comment: and the problem is...?

Comment: If `c.ID` has `NULL`, add `OR c.ID IS NULL` along with the `NOT IN` clause, because `NULL` values need to be handled separately in this case.

Comment: I bet @TomJMuthirenthi is right.  OP, you need to [edit] to let us know what happens when you execute that statement, and why the result isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom J Muthirenthi was right `NULL` values need to be handled separately in this case.

This does the job just right :

```
SELECT c.* FROM CUSTOMERS c WHERE c.ID NOT IN (1,3) OR c.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Query you've posted should work just fine in T-SQL.

Here is official reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Maybe the problem is with the visibility of table and not the query itself?

Comment: Yes the problem was with a data i posted the answer just above